# PHP not getting data but is generating table

Tags: php, minecraft

What I need it to do is go to my database and get the data I have on there. Though it doesn't work. I get a form made with no data in it! It still generates new tables as more data is added just doesnt add the data. Here is my php:

```
 <?php 

 mysql_connect("localhost", "", "")

 or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_select_db("tcordero_playtime") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players") 

 or die(mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    echo "No player information has been entered yet!";
}
else {
 Print "<table border cellpadding=1>"; 

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) 

 { 

 Print "<tr>"; 

 Print "<th>Playername:</th> <td>".$query['playerName'] . "</td> "; 

 Print "<th>Total playtime:</th> <td>".$query['playtime' / 1000 / 60] . "</td> ";

 } 

 Print "</table>"; 
}
 ?>
```

Also the times are in the database in milliseconds. How would I get them to be displayed in minutes or even hours?
Here is an example of the page and what is going wrong: http://tomascordero.com/example/playertime.php

Comment: There seems to be more than one question here. Could point out a specific problem, and errors acssciated with that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$row['playerName']`, etc. instead of `$query['playerName']`. Turn on error logging and it should be more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Change $query into $row in this line:

Before

```
Print "<th>Playername:</th> <td>".$query['playerName'] . "</td> "; 

Print "<th>Total playtime:</th> <td>".$query['playtime' / 1000 / 60] . "</td> ";
```

After

```
Print "<th>Playername:</th> <td>".$row['playerName'] . "</td> "; 

Print "<th>Total playtime:</th> <td>".$row['playtime' / 1000 / 60] . "</td> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$row['playerName']` not `$query['playerName']`.

You are retrieving value to $row so $row should be used to get values.

Also `<tr>` should be closed. In your code `<tr>` is not closing.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your coding like this

> Playername: ".$row['playerName'] . " ";
>
> Print "Total playtime: ".$row['playtime' / 1000 / 60] . "